# git commands "suddenly" requires git@ password

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

After a seemingly successful upgrade from gitlab version 7.14.0 to 7.14.1, git commands suddenly requires a password for git@MyGitlabServer.com. The problem seems to stem from a wrong authorized_keys file for the git user on the gitlab server;

```
$ cat /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
# Managed by gitlab-shell
command="/home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-39",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa [long key here] myemail@server.com
```

However, it seems to be OK:

```
$ gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files: 
    /home/git/repositories/: OK
    /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Test redis-cli executable: redis-cli 2.4.14
Send ping to redis server: PONG
```

All the gitlab post-update control checks are green.

Any ideas?